# better word for an industrial part

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am looking for a generic word that can be used to refer to a fairly large industrial part or component such as a generator, motor, control box or possibly a circuit board.

We are using the word "part" to refer the much smaller items (like screws and wires) the go into the larger things.

What is a good word o use for the larger items that are comprised of parts, which can be used in context with the word "part?"

example: We only use the best parts to fix your parts.

Comment: "to refer to a fairly large industrial part or **component** " what about that?

Comment: Component is pretty much the word used in this situation.  We only use the best parts to fix your components.

Comment: --updates question

Comment: As the old Wendy's commercials said "parts is parts". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTzLVIc-O5E

Comment: life, is, life, du du du tadu

Comment: Thingamajiggy, thingamabob, doodad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Equipment** is the word I typically see for such items, especially if you prefer to not use component.

[Here's](http://www.qerentals.com/catalog.php) a site I've used that relies loosely on a tools/parts/equipment categorization. And [another](http://www.pdqrentals.com/parts-service.asp). Maybe a [third](http://www.simonrents.com/)?

Comment: So far, Eeuipment sounds the best in context.

Answer (score 3):

[*Module*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=module&oq=module) may fit your needs.

A module is comprised of a number of components but is then itself built into larger equipment.

Answer (score 3):

You could call it an *[assembly](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/assembly)* (second definition, meaning 4):-

> *machinery*  a group of mating components before or after fitting together

Answer (score 1):

*Device*, *building block*, *component block* or *apparatus* could work for you.

The owner of a conglomeration of devices, modules, and other equipment probably thinks of it as a *system*. The things you buy could be considered *products*.

We only use the best *parts* (or *products*) to repair your *system* sounds (just) okay to me.

Your *system* will be lovingly constructed of the finest hand-crafted *component blocks*, including the Swiss-made **[Rockwell Retro Encabulator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpnEiOOfu1Q)** *apparatus*.

Comment: Personally, I love it, but it needs to be a bit more salt-of-the-earth.

Answer (score 1):

Another example:

For the small parts I would use **hardware**. Example "We use the best hardware to fix your furniture". Also I would use **industrial machinery** for the bigger ones. "We use the best hardware to fix your industrial machinery".

Comment: Sounds OK, but I would like to use a single word

Answer (score 0):

- Best tools
- Best equipment (as already pointed out by jboneca)

Or

- "We have the best infrastructure for all repairs".

Comment: Could we say, "Hold on to this infrastructure while I drill some holes through it"? Because the OP was looking for another name for an industrial part.

Comment: No we can't say that obviously. But the example of context he gave was related to communication with a customer. So, it might work. In your example, a simple "Hold on to this while I..." will suffice. No need to qualify.